# libsvmread isn't reading data correctly

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I created a file called "image_data_fix2.txt" that has the following format such as in the demo: *Code in Matlab*

```
    +1 1:0.002 2:0.034 3:0.415
    -1 1:0.001 2:0.015 3:-0.917
```

when I use libsvmread, its isn't pulling the data as I want to:
After:

```
    [image_label2, image_features2] = libsvmread(fullfile(dirData,'image_data_fix2.txt'));
```

I'm getting:

```
    image_features(1)
    (1,1) 0.002
    image_features(2)  
    (1,1) 0.034
```

When what I should get should be:

```
    image_features(1)
    (1,1) 0.002
    image_features(2)  
    (1,2) 0.034
```

So I can't fully understand why the datafile I created isn't being read as a sparse matrix.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `image_features2(1)`? Also, visualizing with full matrix is much better than doing the same with sparse matrix. Do `image_features2_full=full(image_features2);` and see how the data is being read.

Comment: Hi Parag, yeah I just found out a bug in my code, I messed up my variables. 
For the record the output of image_features2(1) and image_features2(2) should both have (1,1) indices